# I'm having trouble with matching input from a text file with an item in the array

Tags: java, arrays, output

I am trying to read in from an input file that contains the following:

> Joe Lee, 123 First Street,Omaha,MN,48217-8350

I have an array set up for the scanner to look up the lines in the input file and split them by "," so that I can get the zip code and match each number of the zip code with the items in my array. I am trying to print my output in a txt file. Here is my code:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;

 public class BarCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
   }

    public static String getBarCode(String zipcode) {
    Scanner scanner = null;
  try {
      scanner = new Scanner(new File("addresses.txt"));
   } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Input file not found");
   }

    PrintWriter pw = null;
  try {
     pw = new PrintWriter("labels.txt");
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     System.out.println("Output file not found");
   }

  String[] barcodes = {"||:::", ":::||", "::|:|", "::||:", ":|::|", 
                     ":|:|:", ":||::", "|:::|", "|::|:", "|:|::"};

  String line = scanner.nextLine();
  while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] fields = line.split(",");
    int code = Integer.parseInt(fields[4]);
   }
  }
 }
```

So the output will read this:

```
 Joe Lee
 123 First Street
 Omaha,MN,48217-8350
 And then the symbols that correspond with the zip code
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking here.  Is there a problem with your code?  If so, you need to clarify what this problem is.  If not, you need to get rid of it.

Comment: `48217-8350` is not an `int`, so don't try to parse it as int.

Comment: My question is how would I take each number of the zip code and math it up with the items in my array? So that I can get the corresponding symbol

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Fixed up your code a bit seemed a little messy. Moved your scanner and printer writer along with your loop inside your main method and then left the **getBarCode** method to just convert the zip code into a bar code. Hopefully this helps you.

```
public class BarCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner
        Scanner scanner = null;

        //Create the scanner to the text file
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(new File("src/main/addresses.txt"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Input file not found");
        }

        //Create printwriter
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter("labels.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Output file not found");
        }

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] fields = line.split(",");

            //Get the fields
            String name = fields[0];
            String address = fields[1];
            String city = fields[2];
            String country_code = fields[3];
            String zip_code = fields[4];

            //Convert zip code to bar code string
            String barcodeString = getBarCode(fields[4]);

            //output the the desired output
            pw.println(name);
            pw.println(address);
            pw.println(city+", "+country_code+", "+zip_code);
            pw.println (barcodeString);
        }

        //Close the file to print the data
        pw.close();
    }

    public static String getBarCode(String zipcode) {
        //Barcode string
        String barcode = "";

        //Barcode array
        String[] barcodes = {"||:::", ":::||", "::|:|", "::||:", ":|::|",
                ":|:|:", ":||::", "|:::|", "|::|:", "|:|::"};

        //Get zip code and replace '-'
        zipcode = zipcode.replace("-", "");

        //To char array
        char[] numbers = zipcode.toCharArray();

        //Append array values to barcode string
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            barcode += barcodes[Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numbers[i]))];
        }

        return barcode;
    }
}
```

**Output**

> Joe Lee
>
> 123 First Street
>
> Omaha, MN, 48217-8350
>
> :|::||::|:::|:|:::|||:::||::|:::||::|:|:||:::

Comment: Okay so I ran the code and I changed it up so that it prints the output in the labels.txt file by using this code  `pw.write(name);
                                                          pw.write(address);
                                                          pw.write(city+", "+country_code+", 
                                                          "+zip_code);
                                                          pw.write (barcodeString);`The  labels file still remains blank. Why is that?

Comment: Also what is this part of the code doing? And is there a simpler way to get around this? `char[] numbers = zipcode.toCharArray();` And the same question applies to this part of the code:                                                
                           `for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { `
                            `barcode += `
                            `barcodes[Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numbers[i]))];
                              } `

Comment: numbers converts the zipcode into a character array. inside the for loop, it loops though every character and compares it to your existing array. So if you passed '0' you would get '||:::',

Comment: I edited the post so that it will print to the labels.txt file for you. You probably did not close the printer writer and it did not write @DwightSchrute

Comment: `String.valueOf(numebers[i]);` Converts the character to a string
`Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numebers[i]));` Converts the string to a int